# Expand operator executing more times than expected

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming

I am trying to build some code that paginates result a result set using the expand operator and does so until a certain number of resources has been fetched. This is what I have so far (removed the actual async call logic):

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

const items = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    [11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20],
    [21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30],
];

const call = () => {
    console.log('#call');

    const batch = items.shift();

    if (batch) {
        return Observable.of(batch).delay(100);
    }

    return Observable.empty();
}

const o$ = call().expand((values) => {
    console.log('expansion');
    return call();
}).flatMap((val: any) => val);

const log = (prefix: string) => (...args: any[]) => console.log(prefix, ...args);

o$.take(9).subscribe(log('next'), log('error'), log('complete'));
```

The output is different than what I would want:

```
#call
takeWhile.ts:26 next 1
takeWhile.ts:26 next 2
takeWhile.ts:26 next 3
takeWhile.ts:26 next 4
takeWhile.ts:26 next 5
takeWhile.ts:26 next 6
takeWhile.ts:26 next 7
takeWhile.ts:26 next 8
takeWhile.ts:26 next 9
takeWhile.ts:26 complete
takeWhile.ts:22 expansion
takeWhile.ts:10 #call
```

I get my 9 items, which is what I requested using `take`, then the stream completes, but one additional expansion happens and the mock async API gets called once again.

Is there any way to make my code be less greedy and not start another recursive iteration?

Comment: what's the use of the `flatMap`? Do you want to receive a list of 10 items on every next call, or do you want every next call to have just one item of your multi dimensional array?

Comment: I would prefer to deal with flattened items on the take operator level. Should ideally still be one request and no unnecessary ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing is expected: `expand` is called before `take`, so

- we get the first value
- [expand](https://thinkrx.io/rxjs/expand/) is executed and the call is made
- then the whole observable is immediately unsubscribed from

Therefore you need to make the recursion call asynchronous to let the `take` unsubscribe **before** that call is made. The simplest fix seem to be to substitute `return call();` with a `return timer(4).map(call);` (or even a `return defer(call);`, that magically works :/ ).

**[See this example in action](https://thinkrx.io/gist/25dfe51a29deb6c27300bd6ad09b0ced)**

So generally, you need to make a "pause" / "gap" to let the limiter kick in and unsubscribe.

Hope this helps